# Reference paragraphs without numbering them

Tags: sectioning, numbering, paragraphs, cleveref

If I want to reference a paragraph, but without numbering them, how would I do that?
Currently, I'm doing something along the lines of:

```
\subsection{A}
This is where I'm referring to the paragraph, using cref.
For further information, see \cref{par:X}.

\subsection{B}
Bla bla blub
\paragraph{Paragraph header}\label{par:X}
lorem impsum dolor met sit amet whatever I don't know the rest
```

Unfortunately, this on its own only prints out "..., see subsection [B's number]".

Now, if I use:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\crefname{paragraph}{paragraph}{paragraphs}
\Crefname{paragraph}{paragraph}{paragraphs}
```

in the preamble, I *can* reference paragraphs, instead of just (sub-(sub-))sections.

However, I want to use paragraphs as emphasis inside the text, not as actual numbered headers, which is what is happening now - they get numbered.

**Therefore my question - how do I have to reference my labels so that it renders as "see paragraph *Paragraph Header*" (from the example above) and the actual paragraphs do not get numbers assigned?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reference the title of the paragraph, you can use `\nameref` from the  `hyperref` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\subsection{A}
This is where I'm referring to the paragraph, using cref.
For further information, see \nameref{par:X}.

\subsection{B}
Bla bla blub
\paragraph{Paragraph header}\label{par:X}
lorem impsum dolor met sit amet whatever I don't know the rest


\end{document}
```